# how to change the color of the item when the checkbox is unchecked in c#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox

i want to change the forecolor of the checked item when it is unchecked..
for checked item i have used item.checked but what to do if it is unchecked? im using winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

item.checked is true if an item is checked, and false if an item is unchecked.

So you can do something like:

```
if(item.checked)
{
    //Set color
}
else
{
    //Set color of item for unchecked
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are looking for something like this:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
        checkBox1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    else
        checkBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

As you might know, the Checked property of the CheckBox control is a boolean. So testing for `checkBox1.Checked` results in a changes if Checked == true, and `!checkBox1.Checked` (or an else block) results in changes if Checked == false

Answer (score 3):

```
control.Color = checkBox.Checked ? Color.Red : Color.Blue;
```

Comment: `CheckBox` doesn't have `Color` property